# Attach every database on a folder in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm switching versions of SQL Server (2014 to 2019) in a company that has over 3.000 databases. Migration system keeps crashing on me so I feel like the best way is to just copy the files and attach to the new server, the problem is SSMS can only attach 1 by 1 and it's over 3k companies.

Any way or script to do it by bulk? Attach every `.MDF` database file in a folder to my server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach multiple databases using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835153/attach-multiple-databases-using-t-sql)

Comment: Use Powershell and DBAtools. [Mount-DbaDatabase](https://docs.dbatools.io/Mount-DbaDatabase) is your friend

Answer (score -2):

Create a directory in your server say c:\Test . Inside test place your all MDF files of those 3000 DB's
Now in your SSMS use this command :

```
USE master
GO
EXEC dbo.usp_MultiAttachSingleMDFFiles 'C:\Test' 
GO
```

Comment: "usp_MultiAttachSingleMDFFiles" is a custom procedure, not a built-in function.